# Oracle insert max from two date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create an insert statement in a PL/SQL Script that inserts the larger of two different values. Conceptually, what I want to do is something like

```
Insert into MYTABLE (DATE_INSERT)
VALUE (MAX(DATE_DEFAULT, DATE_INSERT_VALUE))
```

where `DATE_DEFAULT` and `DATE_INSERT_VALUE` are local variables of type `DATE`.  The `MAX` function, however, is an aggregate function so I can't pass two arguments to it.

Comment: Do you really mean PL/SQL? That is for stored procedures/functions triggers. Regular scripts are "only" SQL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `GREATEST` function

```
INSERT INTO my_table( date_column )
 VALUES( GREATEST( date_default, date_insert_value ));
```

Comment: Haha, how could I have forgotten about `GREATEST`? Went straight for `CASE` :)

Comment: `CASE` may be preferred when there are Nulls. `GREATEST(1, NULL)` results in `NULL` and not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but if you just want to insert the larger of two dates you can use a `case` statement (there are lots of other ways of doing this too!):

```
with data as (
  select DATE'2010-01-01' as DATE_INSERT_VALUE, 
         DATE'2010-02-03' as DATE_DEFAULT
  from DUAL
)
select case when DATE_INSERT_VALUE > DATE_DEFAULT then DATE_INSERT_VALUE else DATE_DEFAULT end case 
from data;
```

Comment: Lalala. They're next to each other on the keyboard :P